# GPS coordinates statistics with rotated X & Y axis

Tags: statistics

[image]I have a set of GPS coordinates along with their bearing angle.  These coordinates are within 15 m of each other and so I can use cartesian math to determine the center, std deviation of coordinates etc. I am then trying to find a subset of GPS coordinates that are "above" or "below" the center coordinate. This works well if the road is aligned with the X and Y axis (see fig a below). If the road is at an angle to the X-Y axis (fig b below) how can I determine the center, SD etc for the rotated road?